# Initialize Python dataclass from dictionary

Tags: python

Let's say I want to initialize the below dataclass

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Req:
    id: int
    description: str
```

I can of course do it in the following way:

```py
data = make_request() # gives me a dict with id and description as well as some other keys.
                      # {"id": 123, "description": "hello", "data_a": "", ...}
req = Req(data["id"], data["description"])
```

But, is it possible for me to do it with ***dictionary unpacking***, given that the keys I need ***is always a subset*** of the dictionary?

```py
req = Req(**data)  # TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data_a'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a solution that can be used generically for any class. It simply filters the input dictionary to exclude keys that aren't field names of the class with `init==True`:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields

@dataclass
class Req:
    id: int
    description: str

def classFromArgs(className, argDict):
    fieldSet = {f.name for f in fields(className) if f.init}
    filteredArgDict = {k : v for k, v in argDict.items() if k in fieldSet}
    return className(**filteredArgDict)

data = {"id": 123, "description": "hello", "data_a": ""}
req = classFromArgs(Req, data)
print(req)
```

Output:

```
Req(id=123, description='hello')
```

**UPDATE**: Here's a variation on the strategy above which creates a utility class that caches `dataclasses.fields` for each dataclass that uses it (prompted by a comment by @rv.kvetch expressing performance concerns around duplicate processing of `dataclasses.fields` by multiple invocations for the same dataclass).

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields

class DataClassUnpack:
    classFieldCache = {}

    @classmethod
    def instantiate(cls, classToInstantiate, argDict):
        if classToInstantiate not in cls.classFieldCache:
            cls.classFieldCache[classToInstantiate] = {f.name for f in fields(classToInstantiate) if f.init}

        fieldSet = cls.classFieldCache[classToInstantiate]
        filteredArgDict = {k : v for k, v in argDict.items() if k in fieldSet}
        return classToInstantiate(**filteredArgDict)

@dataclass
class Req:
    id: int
    description: str
req = DataClassUnpack.instantiate(Req, {"id": 123, "description": "hello", "data_a": ""})
print(req)
req = DataClassUnpack.instantiate(Req, {"id": 456, "description": "goodbye", "data_a": "my", "data_b": "friend"})
print(req)

@dataclass
class Req2:
    id: int
    description: str
    data_a: str
req2 = DataClassUnpack.instantiate(Req2, {"id": 123, "description": "hello", "data_a": "world"})
print(req2)

print("\nHere's a peek at the internals of DataClassUnpack:")
print(DataClassUnpack.classFieldCache)
```

Output:

```
Req(id=123, description='hello')
Req(id=456, description='goodbye')
Req2(id=123, description='hello', data_a='world')

Here's a peek at the internals of DataClassUnpack:
{<class '__main__.Req'>: {'description', 'id'}, <class '__main__.Req2'>: {'description', 'data_a', 'id'}}
```

Comment: Neat solution without the need for signature inspection.

Comment: this is not good for performance reasons, beecause it calculates `dataclasses.fields` on each time.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Please see updated answer which shows one way to address your concern.

Comment: Recomend use `parse_raw_as(ParseClassType, dict_data)` `from pydantic import parse_raw_as`

Answer (score 10):

You can possibly introduce a new function that will perform the given conversion from dict to dataclass:

```
import inspect
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Req:
    id: int
    description: str

def from_dict_to_dataclass(cls, data):
    return cls(
        **{
            key: (data[key] if val.default == val.empty else data.get(key, val.default))
            for key, val in inspect.signature(cls).parameters.items()
        }
    )

from_dict_to_dataclass(Req, {"id": 123, "description": "hello", "data_a": ""})
# Output: Req(id=123, description='hello')
```

Note, `if val.default == val.empty` condition is needed in order to check if your dataclass has a default value set. If it's true then we should take the given value into consideration when constructing a dataclass.

Comment: Note that `signature(Req)` shall be `signature(cls)` for general use.

Comment: Awesome post! Should be updated though regarding to the comment from @MathArt

Answer (score 5):

python 3.10 or greater

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Req:
    id: int
    description: str

# invalid keys will cause failure
Req(**{"id": 123, "description": "hello"})
```

Comment: OK Python 3.10 is the version that added support for `kw_only=True`. But your example works just as well without it, on Python < 3.10.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround to this is by intercepting the `__init__` of the [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) and filter out the fields that are not recognized.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields

@dataclass
class Req1:
    id: int
    description: str


@dataclass
class Req2:
    id: int
    description: str

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            if key in REQ2_FIELD_NAMES:
                setattr(self, key, value)

# To not re-evaluate the field names for each and every creation of Req2, list them here.
REQ2_FIELD_NAMES = {field.name for field in fields(Req2)}

data = {
    "id": 1,
    "description": "some",
    "data_a": None,
}

try:
    print("Call for Req1:", Req1(**data))
except Exception as error:
    print("Call for Req1:", error)

try:
    print("Call for Req2:", Req2(**data))
except Exception as error:
    print("Call for Req2:", error)
```

Output:

```
Call for Req1: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data_a'
Call for Req2: Req2(id=1, description='some')
```

Related question:

- [How does one ignore extra arguments passed to a data class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54678337/how-does-one-ignore-extra-arguments-passed-to-a-data-class)

Comment: dont override __init__ in a dataclass!